# Can someone please help me with the solution to this complex integration problem? I do not have the slightest of idea how to proceed.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

> Evaluate $\int_C \frac{1+2z^2}{z}~dz$ where $C$ is the curve starting at $P=i$ and going to $Q=-1$ along the unit circular arc centred at the origin in the anticlockwise direction, followed by a straight line from $Q$ to $R$ at $1+i$.

Someone please guide me through the solution. Thank You.

Comment: Are you familiar with the residue theorem ? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have just started with the residue theorem. I know the theory but haven't been able to apply it practically yet. Someone solving this just as an example would be of great help.

Comment: @AdirthaBorgohain Is my edit correct?

Comment: @projectilemotion Totally correct. Thanks for editing it out.

Comment: Just checking where the gap is: Do you know how to (i) parametrize the circular arc and the line segment? (ii) How to set up a complex integral over a parametrized path? (iii) How to evaluate (complex-valued) one-variable integrals? (Separately, a title that indicates the mathematical nature of your question is likelier to attract helpful attention.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I know i) and I know iii). Partially though. Like I said, I am just starting with this topic. So, still a learner. Can you please send me a link to the related title?

Comment: For (ii), if, say, $z(t) = e^{it}$ or $z(t) = \alpha + \beta t$ for some complex $\alpha$ and $\beta$, the corresponding integral is set up by substituting $z = z(t)$ and $dz = z'(t)\, dt$ and integrating over the interval of parameter values for the path. If this doesn't help, can you say where you're stuck? As for a title, I meant that _editing your question to give a more descriptive title_ (such as "Integrating a meromorphic function over a non-closed path") would be helpful. :)